# Actualizacion de datos sql

Tags: php, sql

Soy nuevo en programar, estoy intentando hacer un formulario, en donde su función es actualizar solamente el precio del material correspondiente, en este caso hay un scrip para que se auto complemente el nombre del material y el código. ¿Cómo hago para que los datos del formularios se envíen y se actualicen por medio de la consulta SQL?

Codigo PHP del formulario a utilizar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>       
      
          
          
          <script >
              $(function() {               
                  //autocomplete
                  $("#material_name").autocomplete({
                     source: "formularios/auto_completar_material2.php", 
                      focus: function(event, ui) {
                          // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                          event.preventDefault();
                          // manually update the textbox
                         //$(this).val(ui.item.label);
                     },
                      select: function(event, ui) {
                          // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                          event.preventDefault();
                          // manually update the textbox and hidden field 
                         $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                         $("#codigo").val(ui.item.cod);
                         $("#cod").val(ui.item.cod);
                         $("#material").val(ui.item.cod);
                         $("#material_name").val(ui.item.label);
                     }                                       
                  });          
              });
          </script>  
              
          
          
        
         
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" hidden/>     
        <table class="display" style=" background-color:  #DCDCDC">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <br>
                        <label style='text-align: center; font-size: 125%'>Asignacion de precio</label>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >                
                <tr>
                    <td>
<form action="precio.php" method="POST">
                        
                        <label >CODIGO:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cod" id="cod" style=" width: 7%" readonly />                        
                        <input type="text" name="material_name" id="material_name" style=" width: 82%"  />                        
                        <!--<a  onclick="limpiar_txt()" class="boton" title="Limpiar Nombre"><-</a>-->
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <label >PRECIO A ASIGNAR:</label>
                                           
                        <input type="number" name="precio_material" id="precio_material" style=" width: 15%"  />
                       
                        <input type="button" value="CONSULTAR" style=" float: right" />
                        <br>
                        <br>

</form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                
            </tfoot>           
        </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php


<?php

require 'conexion.php';
session_start(); 
$codigo = $_POST['cod'];
$precio = $_POST['precio_material'];


if (isset($_POST["asignar"])) 
{
   

    if ($codigo=="" || $precio=="")
    {
        echo "los campos son obligatorios";
    }
    else{

    
   $sql=" UPDATE `movimientos`
    SET `precio`  = IF(`tipo_movimiento` = 'ENTRADA' , '$precio' , `precio`)
    WHERE `codigo_material` = '$codigo' ";
}
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta sql
Como explicacion, en la tabla movimientos hay una columna llamada tipo_movimiento, se estaria actualizando el precio en la columna tipo_movimiento cada vez que se "ENTRADA"

Precio.php

```
UPDATE `movimientos`
    SET `precio` = IF( `movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento` = 'ENTRADA' , $precio , `precio`)
    WHERE `movimientos`.`codigo_material` = '$codigo'
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está la etiqueta `<form action="???" method="???">` en el html?

Comment: en este momento lo añadi, ahi solo tendria que crear otro archivo con el metodo isset POST?

Comment: En `"ENTRADA"` tienes comillas dobles, que finalizan la cadena de la consulta y, seguramente, estás obteniendo un error de sintaxis. Cambia por comillas simples y prueba a ver si funciona. Lo mismo para el valor de `codigo_material`.

Comment: ya lo corregí, antes ni ahora aparece ningun error, solo como que el boton no tiene ninguna funcion

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\mantenimientoC\formularios\precio.php on line 25, nos eporque me apree ese error ahora

Comment: Revisa atentamente tu código. En PHP cada línea debe terminar por `;`, veo al menos tres líneas que no terminan con  punto y coma. Esta: `$codigo = $_POST['cod']` y esta: `$material = $_POST['material_name']` y esta: `$precio = $_POST['precio_material']` ... puede que haya más casos así, revisa bien el código.

Comment: disculpas que no habia editado bien esa parte, pero ya habia corregido ese error, en este momento se edito d enuevo